# How to write a script for signup on spring boot with angularjs

Tags: javascript

Our project is on spring boot with docker using angularjs for front-end. We use protractor for front-end tests. I want to write a script for easy signup by giving parameters. How can I do this and integrate to project?

For example, may I use a python script? I don't want to use protractor, because it is for testing.